# SQL SELECT TOP 1 FOR EACH GROUP

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I have had a look through the other questions and can't quite find what i'm looking for I have an SQL Database and in it a table called InventoryAllocations. In the table I have multiple entries for DocumentID's and want to retrieve the last entry for each unique DocumentID. I can retrieve just one by doing

```
SELECT  top(1) [UID]
      ,[RecordStatusID]
      ,[CreatedDate]
      ,[CreatedTime]
      ,[CreatedByID]
      ,[OperationType]
      ,[InventoryLocationID]
      ,[DocumentTypeID]
      ,[DocumentID]
      ,[SOJPersonnelID]
      ,[InventorySerialisedItemID]
      ,[TransactionQty]
      ,[TransactionInventoryStatusID]
      ,[Completed]
      ,[CreatedByType]
      ,[RecordTimeStamp]
  FROM [CPData].[dbo].[InventoryAllocations]
  order by DocumentID desc
```

but I want it to bring back a list containing all the unique DocumentID's.I hope you can help. Many Thanks Hannah x

Comment: Have you tried following instructions at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618559/select-top-record-for-each-year ? I believe that TOP OVER PARTITION BY is basically the pattern you need here.

Comment: Last entry - according to which column(s)?

Comment: The last entry could be determined by either the newest CreatedDate or the biggest UID for each unique DocumentID.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES 
    [UID]
    ,[RecordStatusID]
    ,[CreatedDate]
    ,[CreatedTime]
    ,[CreatedByID]
    ,[OperationType]
    ,[InventoryLocationID]
    ,[DocumentTypeID]
    ,[DocumentID]
    ,[SOJPersonnelID]
    ,[InventorySerialisedItemID]
    ,[TransactionQty]
    ,[TransactionInventoryStatusID]
    ,[Completed]
    ,[CreatedByType]
    ,[RecordTimeStamp]
FROM 
    [CPData].[dbo].[InventoryAllocations]
ORDER BY
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DocumentID ORDER BY [RecordTimeStamp] DESC);
```

`TOP 1` works with `WITH TIES` here.

`WITH TIES` means that when `ORDER BY = 1`, then `SELECT` takes this record (because of `TOP 1`) and all others that have `ORDER BY = 1` (because of `WITH TIES`).

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!! Thanks everyone else for taking the time to look and comment too x

Comment: Thanks Vadim, this helped me as well

Comment: This is a lovely solution!

Comment: Is this a performance conscious solution as well?

Answer (score 10):

```
You can use a RowNumber() Window Function.

SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARITION BY [DOCUMENTID] ORDER BY [RecordTimeStamp] DESC) AS RowNumber, 
          ,[RecordStatusID]
          ,[CreatedDate]
          ,[CreatedTime]
          ,[CreatedByID]
          ,[OperationType]
          ,[InventoryLocationID]
          ,[DocumentTypeID]
          ,[DocumentID]
          ,[SOJPersonnelID]
          ,[InventorySerialisedItemID]
          ,[TransactionQty]
          ,[TransactionInventoryStatusID]
          ,[Completed]
          ,[CreatedByType]
          ,[RecordTimeStamp]
      FROM [CPData].[dbo].[InventoryAllocations] ) as A 
WHERE RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: "I want to retrieve the last entry for each unique DocumentID" - this will bring back the highest document ID per UID, not what was originally requested!

Comment: You are right, my bad I read it the other way. I changed the Partition and this should work. I like using window functions as they are more efficient. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This gives each record a row, taking each document ID and then giving the latest created_date a row_number of 1, and each row before that an increment of 1. We then select the records with a rowno of 1 to get the latest created date per document ID:

```
SELECT [UID]
,[RecordStatusID]
,[CreatedDate]
,[CreatedTime]
,[CreatedByID]
,[OperationType]
,[InventoryLocationID]
,[DocumentTypeID]
,[DocumentID]
,[SOJPersonnelID]
,[InventorySerialisedItemID]
,[TransactionQty]
,[TransactionInventoryStatusID]
,[Completed]
,[CreatedByType]
,[RecordTimeStamp]
FROM
(
SELECT  
[UID]
,[RecordStatusID]
,[CreatedDate]
,[CreatedTime]
,[CreatedByID]
,[OperationType]
,[InventoryLocationID]
,[DocumentTypeID]
,[DocumentID]
,[SOJPersonnelID]
,[InventorySerialisedItemID]
,[TransactionQty]
,[TransactionInventoryStatusID]
,[Completed]
,[CreatedByType]
,[RecordTimeStamp]
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DOCUMENT_ID ORDER BY CreatedDate) DESC AS ROWNO
FROM [CPData].[dbo].[InventoryAllocations] 
)
WHERE ROWNO = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically like this.

```
with cte as
(
    SELECT [UID]
        , [RecordStatusID]
        , [CreatedDate]
        , [CreatedTime]
        , [CreatedByID]
        , [OperationType]
        , [InventoryLocationID]
        , [DocumentTypeID]
        , [DocumentID]
        , [SOJPersonnelID]
        , [InventorySerialisedItemID]
        , [TransactionQty]
        , [TransactionInventoryStatusID]
        , [Completed]
        , [CreatedByType]
        , [RecordTimeStamp]
        , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by DocumentID order by DocumentID desc) as RowNum
    FROM   [CPData].[dbo].[InventoryAllocations]
)

select [UID]
    , [RecordStatusID]
    , [CreatedDate]
    , [CreatedTime]
    , [CreatedByID]
    , [OperationType]
    , [InventoryLocationID]
    , [DocumentTypeID]
    , [DocumentID]
    , [SOJPersonnelID]
    , [InventorySerialisedItemID]
    , [TransactionQty]
    , [TransactionInventoryStatusID]
    , [Completed]
    , [CreatedByType]
    , [RecordTimeStamp]
from cte
where RowNum = 1
order by DocumentID desc
```

Comment: By not sorting by a date in the row_number clause you can't be confident that you will get the right results, or even consistent results.

Comment: The results would be consistent, just not what the OP wanted. It should have been ordered by RecordTimeStamp.