# Joining SQL Tables with Conditions (Turning a 1:Many Join to 1:1)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Unsure on how to word my question/title, so if anyone has any suggestions to best reach what I am after, it would be much appreciated!

In summary:

I have the following tables,

```
[Items] [I]
Id Date  Name 
1  07/11 Ball
2  07/11 Bat

[Prices] [P]
Id Date  Name Price
1  05/11 Ball 10.50
2  05/11 Bat  21.00
3  06/11 Ball 10.75
4  06/11 Bat  22.00
5  07/11 Ball 10.25
6  07/11 Bat  20.25
```

I want to create a script that links the two tables, but only pulls the latest price (the id's are increasing in line with increasing dates)

So I would want my result to be:

```
Id Name Price 
1  Ball 10.25
2  Bat  20.25
```

If I do a simple join:

```
SELECT * FROM [ITEMS] [I]
LEFT JOIN [PRICES] [P] On [I].[NAME] = [P].[NAME]
WHERE [I].[DATE] = '2018-11-07'
```

Then I end up with 6 rows for each day with a price. I can obviously change it and add [P].[DATE] = '2018-11-07' to the end, so that it prices, but I would like it to pick up the latest date (in case the item doesn't receive price one day, I can use the one from the day before)

I have found the following code:

```
SELECT * FROM [ITEMS] [I]
LEFT JOIN [PRICES] [P] On [I].[NAME] = [P].[NAME]
WHERE [I].[DATE] = '2018-11-07' 
AND [P].[ID] = 
(SELECT max([ID]) FROM [PRICES] WHERE [NAME] = 'Ball')
```

Which works perfectly, but only for the item of WHERE [NAME] = '...' It looks like this may be the way to go, but I can't think how to change the code so that it does it for all of my items.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: mySql <> Sql Server. Based on the use of square brackets, I've removed the MySql tag from your question.

Comment: Similar problem (and solution): [SELECT TOP record for each year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9618559/select-top-record-for-each-year)

Comment: The P condition in the WHERE clause makes the LEFT JOIN return regular INNER JOIN result. Move that condition to the ON clause to get true LEFT JOIN result.

Comment: @GolezTrol
Thanks for posting this. Do you know to change this, so that it selects the LAST row rather than the FIRST?

Comment: I'd say: Add `desc` to the order by clause, the one inside the `row_number`

Comment: @GolezTrol Strangely that only seems to give me a one row result..

Answer (score 2):

You can use `TOP WITH Ties`

```
 SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES * 
 FROM [ITEMS] [I]
 LEFT JOIN [PRICES] [P] On [I].[NAME] = [P].[NAME]
 ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY I.NAME ORDER BY [I].[DATE] DESC)
```

Comment: Thanks @Sanal Sunny.

I have changed the code above to the following, which seems to work:
    SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES * 
    FROM [ITEMS] [I]LEFT JOIN [PRICES] [P] On [I].[NAME] = [P].[NAME]
    WHERE [I].[DATE] = '2018-11-07' ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY I.NAME ORDER BY [I].[DATE] DESC)

However, this does it for the first row (i.e. the first price in the list) not the last, do you know what adjustment I need to make it so that it picks up the last?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TOP WITH TIES` but you don't need window functions:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES *
FROM [ITEMS] [I] LEFT JOIN
     [PRICES] [P] 
     ON [I].[NAME] = [P].[NAME]
ORDER BY [I].[DATE] DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option (Version 2012 or higher) is to use the `First_value` window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
        I.Id, 
        I.[Name], 
        FIRST_VALUE(P.Price) OVER(PARTITION BY I.[Name] ORDER BY P.[Date])
FROM Items As I
LEFT JOIN Prices As P
    ON I.[Name] = P.[Name]
```